# how to find the solution for this inequality?

Tags: inequality

The question is $(2+\sqrt3)^{x^2-x}+(2-\sqrt3)^{x^2-x}\ge14$

how will i proceed with this question?

I'm not able to think of any idea of how to solve this question

please help with this question

Comment: Try to prove the function is monotone in certain interval(may have inf. endpoint) using calculus techniques.

Comment: A graph might help. https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=(2%2Bsqrt(3))%5E(x%5E2-x)%2B(2-sqrt(3))%5E(x%5E2-x)

Comment: is it possible using rules of logarithm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $2-\sqrt 3=\dfrac1{2+\sqrt3}$. And you should be able to proceed.

As a rule of thumb, every time you have something like $A^x+B^x=C$, you either find a trick like the one above or you have little hope for an algebraic solution.

Comment: still not able to figure how to proceed

Comment: Solve $T+\frac1T\ge14$ for appropriate $T$.

Comment: :} understood..